# Check Constraint for 1 of 2 composite primary keys

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-key-relationship

I understand that Foreign Key constraint is not possible if I only want to enforced it only on 1 of the composite primary keys (I currently have 2). So I would like to use Check Constraint to implement it but I can't find any example to start with.

I have `TableA` with `C1` & `C2` as composite primary key. Then `TableB` with `C1` & `C3`, but I only want to enforce C1 between TableA and TableB.

Thanks.

EDIT: Think of TableA as personal detail, and TableB as phone numbers of the person. So I want to make sure that TableB only contains phone numbers for valid existing persons in TableA. C2 of TableA which is part of the composite key, existed due to design and currently can't be changed.

Comment: Please explain in more details what is the purpose and the relationship of the tables. A column (or set of columns) must be either unique or the primary key to be the target of an FK reference.

Comment: What does *"I only want to enforce C1 between TableA and TableB."* mean? Do you want for a row to be inserted into B, to already exist a row (or more) in A, with the same `C1`? Or the other way around?

Comment: Are you saying that `C1`, in and of itself, is sufficient to identify a particular row in `TableA`? If so, there's no restriction on adding an additional key (`UNIQUE`) on just that column and implementing a plain FK constraint. If it's not true, then in what way does the `C1` column in `TableB` reference something in `TableA` if multiple rows can have the same `C1` value?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I didn't realize I could do that. But TableA doesn't belong to us, so I can't actually modify it. I'll make a request to the module owner. Thanks

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've added `UNIQUE` key to TableA C1, and that solve the FK reference. Do you mind to post it as an answer?